# C - Struct allocation in function

Tags: c, function, memory-management, struct

I'm trying to allocate a struct array inside a function, but when I return to main it's like the memory that I just allocated has been overwritten. That's my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Class {
  int students;
  Person * N;
};

struct Person
{
  char * name;
  int age;
};

void allocation(struct Class ** myclasspointer)
{
    struct Class *mytempstruct= malloc(sizeof *mytempstruct); 
    mytempstruct -> students = 10;
    char *n= "My name is...?";

    mytempstruct -> N = malloc (sizeof (mytempstruct -> N) * 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mytempstruct -> N[i].age = i;
        mytempstruct -> N[i].name = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n));
        strncpy (N[i].name, n, strlen(n));
    }

    *myclasspointer = mytempstruct;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  struct class * MyClass;

  allocation(&MyClass);

  for (int i = 0; i < MyClass.students; i++)
     Prinf("Student %s, age %d: %d \n",  MyClass->N[i].name, MyClass->N[i].age);

  for (int i = 0; i < MyClass->students; i++)
     free(MyClass->N[i]);
  free (MyClass);

  return 0;
}
```

Once I go back to main, only some values are as they should. I also tryed to change:

```
void allocation(struct Class ** myclasspointer)
{
    struct Class *mytempstruct= malloc(sizeof *mytempstruct); 

    char *n= "My name is...?";

    mytempstruct -> N = malloc (sizeof (mytempstruct -> N) * 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mytempstruct -> N[i].age = i;
        mytempstruct -> N[i].name = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n));
    }

    *myclasspointer = mytempstruct;
}
```

to:

```
void allocation(struct Class ** myclasspointer)
{
    myclasspointer= malloc(sizeof *myclasspointer); 

    char *n= "My name is...?";

    myclasspointer-> N = malloc (sizeof (myclasspointer-> N) * 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mytempstruct -> N[i].age = i;
        mytempstruct -> N[i].name = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n));
    }
}
```

But I have the same result.

Comment: Your code would not even compile!

Comment: `strncpy(dst, src, strlen(src))` accomplishes nothing over `strcpy(dst, src)` (other than giving some people a false sense of security).

Comment: What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n));` --> `malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n)+1));`

Comment: `free(MyClass->N[i]);` --> `free(MyClass->N[i].name);` and add `free(MyClass->N);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a forward declaration of `person`. Then change

```
mytempstruct -> N = malloc (sizeof (mytempstruct -> N) * 10);  
                                   ^will give the size of pointer instead of structure `person`
```

to

```
mytempstruct -> N = malloc (sizeof (struct person) * 10);
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Sorry but I tryed to make an example instead of posting the wole program and I forgot to add too many things!

Answer (score 1):

```
    mytempstruct -> N[i].name = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n)) );
    strncpy (N[i].name, n, strlen(n));
```

is wrong you want:

```
    mytempstruct -> N[i].name = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen(n)+1) );
    strncpy (N[i].name, n, strlen(n)+1);
```

for space for the null character.

Comment: you missed a `)` at the end of malloc